# Orthogonal of $K=\{f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \mid \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}: \int^{n+1}_n f(x)dx = 0 \}$ in $L^2(\mathbb R)$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, integration

Define a subspace $K \subset L^2(\mathbb{R})$ given by $$K=\{f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \mid \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}: \int^{n+1}_n f(x)dx = 0 \}.$$

I have already proven that $K$ is closed by using a convergence theorem (is this correct?). I want to find $K^{\perp}$. I'm quite confused on how to find this. I first tried writing down $\langle f,g \rangle$ with $g \in K$ and $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ to find a condition for $f$, but I'm stuck there.

Comment: You can split any $g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ as $g = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} g_n\chi_{[n,n+1)} + (g - g_n)\chi_{[n,n+1)}$ where, $g_n = \int_{n}^{n+1} g \,dx$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ .. that tells you what the orthogonal decomposition should be ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

*$K$ is closed*

The map

\begin{array}{l|rcl}
\psi_n : & L^2(\mathbb{R}) & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\
    & f & \longmapsto & \int_n^{n+1} f(x) \ dx\end{array}
is continuous, hence its kernel is closed.

$$K = \bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb Z} \psi_n^{-1}[\{0\}]$$ is closed as an intersection of closed subsets.

*About $K^\perp$*

You know that on $(0,1)$, $\{\sin 2\pi nx, \cos 2\pi nx \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2((0,1))$. They all belong to $K$, except the constant map.

Hence an element $\phi$ of $K^\perp$ has to be constant on each interval $(n, n+1)$.

You also need to have $\int_{\mathbb R} f^2$ convergent. Finally, $K^\perp$ is the subset of $ L^2(\mathbb{R})$ generated by the indicator functions of the intervals $[n,n+1]$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: This is very clear! Thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 2):

You can convince yourself that the orthogonal space must include the span of the set of indicators of the segments (n,n+1). On the other hand every function in the orthogonal space must be constant on such segments up to a set of measure zero (there are details to complete here), so both inclusions apply.

Edit: K is alredy the orthogonal space to the space of these indicators, so use the fact the orthogonal of the orthogonal is the closure of the span.

Comment: I don't see what you get for $K^{\perp}$?

Comment: AlgSpan{1_(n,n+1)| n is integer} (it is closed so it is the closure of itself)

Comment: Could you elaborate your point? I have a hard time understanding what you mean

Comment: For each segment (n,n+1) for n in Z take the indicator functon 1n that is constantly 1 in (n,n+1) and vanish elswhere. Take the set of all these indicators, denote it I. Its algebraic span is the regular set of all finite linear combinations. Denote this span by S=span(I). So I^⊥ is exactly K. Therefore K^⊥=(I^⊥)^⊥ and the latter equals cl(span(I)) (cl stands for the topological closure). S=span(I) is closed and thus S is the desired K^⊥. Is it clear now? If not which step makes troubles?

Comment: I advise you to write your math and symbols in LaTeX here, they are quite strict about this. I refer to the answer of mathcounterexamples.net, much easier and more clear to read and understand. cheers!

Comment: How do I do this? Also, is there a way to do this while using the phone?

Comment: Have you ever worked with LaTeX ? If not, there are multiple guides online and even in the help section here.